# How do I remove app from iOS 8 Simulator from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6, build-automation

I have an automation running in the iOS Simulator that I have to remove before another run. How do I remove the app from the iOS Simulator from the command line?

For each simulator device directory (located at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*`), I 
tried to delete `./data/Containers/Bundle/Application/` and `./data/Containers/Data/Application/`.

Even when I tried to delete the app by long pressing the app in the Simulator (the app becomes jiggly) and click on the X button, the user defaults were not being cleared. I want the app state to be 100% clean.

I found a good solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One approach that we found for deleting user defaults is to delete all files in the `./data/Library/Preferences/*` in addition to deleting application and data directories.

However, in Xcode 6, the command `xcrun` has new subcommand called `simctl` that allows me to manage iOS Simulator including resetting the simulator, and installing the application.

The solution that I came up with is to use the command

```sh
xcrun simctl erase [device ID]
```

***Example***

If `xcrun simctl list`(**†**) returns

```
9DDA0CFE-7CEC-40B6-A343-1EC01F282B22 (active, disconnected)
    Watch: Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm (88474523-163E-4021-B591-2AECBFA26997) (Shutdown)
    Phone: iPhone 7 Plus (5785E680-15CD-42D3-82AB-597286A270C5) (Shutdown)
```

then run these 2 commands

```sh
xcrun simctl erase 88474523-163E-4021-B591-2AECBFA26997
xcrun simctl erase 5785E680-15CD-42D3-82AB-597286A270C5
```

---

(**†**) **The device ID can be obtained from running**

```sh
xcrun simctl list
```

This will reset the simulator (equivalent to `iOS Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings...` menu item).

With Xcode 6.0.1 (Build 6A317), there is either a bug or a change in behavior where when you uninstall an application, user defaults are not removed.

```
Usage: simctl [--noxpc] [--set <set path>] <subcommand> ... | help [subcommand]
Command line utility to control the iOS Simulator

For subcommands that require a <device> argument, you may specify a device UDID
or the special "booted" string which will cause simctl to pick a booted device.
If multiple devices are booted when the "booted" device is selected, simctl
will choose one of them.

Subcommands:
    create        Create a new device.
    delete        Delete a device.
    erase         Erase a device's contents and settings.
    boot          Boot a device.
    shutdown      Shutdown a device.
    rename        Rename a device.
    getenv        Print an environment variable from a running device.
    openurl       Open a URL in a device.
    addphoto      Add a photo to the photo library of a device.
    install       Install an app on a device.
    uninstall     Uninstall an app from a device.
    launch        Launch an application by identifier on a device.
    spawn         Spawn a process on a device.
    list          List available devices, device types, or runtimes.
    notify_post   Post a darwin notification on a device.
    icloud_sync   Trigger iCloud sync on a device.
    help          Prints the usage for a given subcommand.
```

Comment: If all you want to do is delete the single app, you should use uninstall instead of erase.

Comment: In Xcode 6.0.1, even if you use uninstall command, the user defaults remain intact (it's a bug). That's why I suggest using erase.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Good point, however that is not an issue with Xcode 6.0.1 but with iOS 8.0.  If you use 'delete' on a simulated 7.x device, it will work fine.

Answer (score 59):

With Xcode 6.1, to uninstall an app, use the following command:

```
xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog
```

where `com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog` is the bundle identifier of the application you wish to uninstall.

Comment: This is a much cleaner implementation, especially with the inclusion of 'booted'

Comment: Is there a way to fail silently if there is no booted simulator?

Comment: I guess I could simply do `xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog || true`.

Comment: When running on several simulator devices simultaneously, the one on which the app in uninstalled is undefined. In that case, use the UDID of the device instead of `booted` (get the available UDIDs with `xcrun simctl list`)

Comment: exactly what we needed! I searched for method to wipe all contents while developing UITests every time it starts.

Comment: In completion to the @atineoSE suggestion if you want only the list of running simulators use the command: `xcrun simctl list | grep "Booted"`. Then you can remove the app from a specific simulator with: `xcrun simctl uninstall [UDID] [BUNDLE_ID]`.

Answer (score 11):

## Reset all Content & Settings in a single command

1. Quit iPhone Simulator
2. In Terminal, run:

   ```
   xcrun simctl erase all
   ```

This will reset content and settings of all the simulators for the active version of Xcode (the one referenced by `xcode-select -p`).

Answer (score 5):

```
xcrun simctl uninstall simulatorIdentifier appBundleId
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is a decade-old question, but things have changed since, though the necessity to test on clean installation is still there. None of the answers above seem quite satisfactory to me so I propose another solution.

### I propose a method safe with respect to different device/simulator ids as well as bundle id:

```bash
if [[ "$RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME" == "iphonesimulator" ]]; then
    xcrun simctl uninstall $RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UDID $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
else
    xcrun devicectl device uninstall app --device $RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UDID $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
fi
```

### To automate it and run as a part of your development workflow:

1. Add a custom scheme, let's say `CleanInstall`:

[image]

2. Add `New Run Script Action` to `Run` phase's `Pre-actions`:

[image]

[image]

3. Make sure to "Provide build settings from" your target to gain access to `$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` which is inaccessible at `Run` phase as is:

[image]

4. Paste script above

### Resulting setup should look like this:

[image]

---

### Design considerations, differences from other methods:

Pros:

1. Fully automated: no need for manual touches on device/simulator, or manual terminal commands invocation
2. Doesn't require third-party tools like
   `libmobiledevice`
3. Doesn't require you to remember or even know bundle id or destination device/simulator id. No need for `xcrun simctl list`, Xcode provides everything for you
4. Erases *only* the required app, doesn't require you to do a full wipe of simulator unlike `xcrun simctl erase` (arguably a pro or con depending on your situation, see below)
5. Erases an app exactly from destination device/simulator specified in Xcode when running an app, unlike `xcrun simctl uninstall booted` where there could be multiple devices/simulators opened/connected at the same time and behaviour may be kind of undefined
6. Naturally extends to unit testing both from Xcode UI and command-line assuming you specify the scheme

Cons:

1. To my knowledge this doesn't (and shouldn't) erase keychain items. So unless you're testing keychain items/groups you should be fine.
2. While researching this question I realised there are some apps that rely on safari caches (WKWebView users?) and there are chances that safari caches might be unaffected by only app deletion and persist after that?

In both of these cases feel free to create another scheme similar to the above with something like `xcrun simctl erase $RUN_DESTINATION_DEVICE_UDID`. Be careful with real devices though!