# How can I delete the app between test cases in a Unit test target?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, kif

I'm using KIF to do some testing and it uses a unit test target. Since I can't access XCUIApplication , I'm not able to reproduce an app delete which I would need to reset the app state to run the following test case **(so between tests)**. Furthermore, I've tried running this script as a build phase script without success :

```
/usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.mycompany.bundleId
```

I've added it to the same test target where I'm doing the test cases, check how [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG1ji.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove app from iOS 8 Simulator from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394596/how-do-i-remove-app-from-ios-8-simulator-from-command-line)

Comment: @bbarnhart not a duplicate. I'm trying to do it between test cases, I do know how to remove it from the command line.